# JDK17+: Why is it not possible to have a single switch branch match on multiple type patterns?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Just wondering what the design rationale for this is/was.

I can do

```
int x = ...
switch( x ) {
    case 1,2 -> { ... stuff ...}
    default -> { ... something else ...}
}
```

but trying to do something like

```
 Object x = ...
 switch( x ) {
   case String, Integer x -> { ... stuff ...}
   default -> { ... something else ...}
 }
```

does not compile (I also tried things like "String x, Integer x" and "String|Integer x" but neither of them compile).

If I understood the [JLS](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/17/latestSpec/specs/patterns-switch-jls.html#jls-14.30.1) correctly, it's simply not supported - does anybody know why this is the case and if this will ever be fixed ?

Comment: `String` and `Integer` have almost nothing in common. How would such an `x` be useful at all?

Comment: This is covered in the JEP ([JEP 420](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/420))

Comment: They are both `Constable` and a `ConstantDesc`. Might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

After reading JEP-420 again I found an explanation:

[image: JEP-420]

I still think this should be possible if the body of the branch does not actually refer to the case labels, for example in code like this (ApplicationState is a sealed class with several subclasses, note that I cannot use an enum here as some of the states need to hold mutable data):

```
private static ApplicationState checkValidTransition(ApplicationState from, ApplicationState to )
{
    final boolean isValidTransition = switch(from) {
        case Uninitialized ignored -> to instanceof ServletContextInitializing;
        case Destroyed ignored -> to instanceof ServletContextInitializing;
        case ServletContextInitializing ignored -> to instanceof SpringContextInitializing || to instanceof Destroyed;
        case SpringContextInitializing ignored -> to instanceof SpringContextInitializing || to instanceof Destroyed || to instanceof WebApplicationInitFinished;
        case WebApplicationInitFinished ignored -> to instanceof Destroyed;
    };
    if ( ! isValidTransition ) {
        throw new IllegalStateException( "Internal error, illegal state transition " + from + " -> " + to );
    }
    return to;
}
```